# This page contains the following errors: error on line 2 at column 6: XML declaration allowed only at the start of the document

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing, pear

I am unable to find out the solution , please help. below is the code. Thanks in advance

```
    require_once "db.php";
    $sQuery = "SELECT price ,year,carID FROM cars ";

    $result = $conn->query($sQuery);
    $dom = new DOMDocument( "1.0");

    $root = $dom->createElement('cars');

    while($row = $result->fetch()){
        $car_node = $dom->createElement('car');

        $car_id = $row['carID'];
        $car_node->setAttribute( "id", $car_id); 

        $car_year = $row['year'];
        $car_year_node = $dom->createElement('year' ,$car_year);
        $car_node->appendChild($car_year_node);

        $root->appendChild($car_node);
}   $dom->appendChild($root); 

    header('Content-Type: application/xml');
    $dom->formatOutput = true;
    print $dom->saveXML();  
?>
```

and here is the db.php connect file

```
<?php

$server_name = "localhost"; $user_name = "root"; $password = ""; $db_name = "databse";
try
{
 $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$server_name;dbname=$db_name", $user_name, $password);
}
catch(PDOException $e)
 {
    echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
 }
?>
```

and meanwhile i keep getting the same error

```
This page contains the following errors:
error on line 2 at column 6: XML declaration allowed only at the start of the document
Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.
```

help me please need this very fast for a university assignment due next week

Comment: How does your output look like? The error message says, that there is content before the xml declaration. Possibly a PHP error, warning or notice is thrown before the ouput. Would be nice to know how the stack trace of the error looks like.

Comment: It's generally best to avoid saying that you need a solution urgently. Some people will avoid getting involved in a situation where you're in a rush to meet a deadline.

Comment: Have you tried contacting your professor? Mine at least were very responsive about helping me with homework problems and had already seen many of the common errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove all blank space before `<?` and after `?>` in your files.

Comment: To elaborate on _in your files_, this means the root page and the entire `require` and `require_once` hierarchy from that root page.